# SQL UPDATE/WHERE Help... Updating columns not defined by WHERE

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

Basic SQL UPDATE and Access 2007 vba question. Can someone explain to me why this query is also updating `BoxType` "60ct Shipper Tray" and not just the 60ct Shipper Pieces declared in the `WHERE` statement? Thank you!

```
ElseIf Me!txtBoxType = "60ct Shipper Tray" Then

 'Cases that use a 60tray are more complicated. They use 1 each of the base, header, and display
 'aswell as 3 shelves.

qdf.SQL = "UPDATE tblBoxList Set Qty = (Qty+(" & Me!txtQtyChange & ")) WHERE BoxType = '60ct Shipper Base' OR '60ct Shipper Header' OR '60ct Shipper Display';"
qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
```

Comment: I won't say that the answer of why your double calculating isn't in this code snippit, but I will say that you can debug it way easier than we can with the database in front of you. Perhaps you need a lesson in using the debugger. Create a testing region for your database, set all quantities to 60, go to your VBA editor, show the watch window, right click the watch window and add a watch, set the value of the watch to your "Shipper Tray" variable, set the watch type to "Break when value changes", try a calculation. If you're adjusting the value twice, it'll break twice, and you can see where.

Comment: Ive isolated the problem in the code. Thx for the the debugger advice. @BillN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the field name in each of those conditions you `OR` together.  Use a `SELECT` query to work out the `WHERE` clause logic.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM tblBoxList 
WHERE
       BoxType = '60ct Shipper Base'
    OR BoxType = '60ct Shipper Header'
    OR BoxType = '60ct Shipper Display'
```

You might prefer this approach instead.

```sql
WHERE BoxType IN
    (
        '60ct Shipper Base',
        '60ct Shipper Header',
        '60ct Shipper Display'
    )
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir! I really hate to handle exceptional situations like this (exception where a case can be composed of more then one box type) by adding additional conditionals to the code. But the time is just not there to redo the whole access project atm. @HansUp